# MS Outlook - Scheduling Assistant - choose view

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Is it possible to configure MS Outlook so that, when using the Scheduling Assistant, I see the items from my calendar based on a given View?

I have some recurring meetings that are optional (I attend them from time to time, as time allows). In order to better visualize my calendar I use different views, which filter out certain calendar items according to their category (Blue, Green, etc).

I would like to have the same possibility in the Scheduling Assistant. I can't find any setting for it though.

Thanks in advance!

Joao Silva

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a custom view for scheduling assistant? As far as I know, there is currently no official documentation indicating that view settings can be made for the scheduling assistant.
In addition, I found a case that the scheduling assistant does not support view settings：

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-scheduling-assistant-timescale-view/a29ec22e-bbde-4162-932b-bbaa332c43e0

If you think my answer is help, please accept my answer to help other people.